# CakePHP: Always use clear() instead of create()?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

there's a small, but very important difference, between calling `clear()` and `create()` within a loop:

let's assume the following code:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $this->Post->create();
  $this->Post->id = $post['Post']['id'];
  $this->Post->save(['column3' => 'foo', 'column4' => 'bar']);
}
```

When doing a `create()`:
column 1, which might default to boolean false, is magically added to the updated-fields as well and can lead to a data loss (think of post with column1 = true).

When doing a `clear()` instead of `create()`:
column 1, which is not mentioned in the save-statement is not touched at all.

So, is it always safe to rely on `clear()` in a foreach, where existing data is partially updated?

Second party of my question:
Is it **ALWAYS** better to rely on `clear()`? (When looking at the code of `clear()`, you see, that it's only a convenience wrapper for `create(false)`). And the only difference in `create()` and `create(false)` is the initialization of the default values. I think, default values should better be set directly on database-level.

Btw: I just proposed a [small doc change](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/1440). Feel free to +1 this:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, is it always safe to rely on clear() in a foreach, where existing data is partially updated?

Yes.

> Is it ALWAYS better to rely on clear()?

The only benefit of using `create()` when **adding** records is your form will be pre-populated with default values to be shown to user. So if you don't care about this you can always use `clear()`.

Comment: *your form will be pre-populated with default values to be shown to user* -- could you please elaborate?